Does the angular kinetic energy of a point mass always correspond to its linear kinetic energy?
Let's assume a point mass is moving with constant speed on a linear trajectory.
Its angular kinetic energy is given by the formula:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$
Does this energy correspond to the linear kinetic energy of the point
$$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
or to the energy of just one component (the perpendicular component to the radius) of the speed?

What angular motion is there to speak of if the particle is moving in a straight line?

A particle moving in a straight line is actually rotating around any point not lying on the line, because the angle formed by the particle with the point changes over time.

The two equations describe the same motion. just substitute $mR^2$ for $I$ and $v^{2}/R^2$ for $\omega ^2$.

Bob, your comment is an answer, please repeat it as answer.

Let's assume the point mass is moving at constant velocity $v$ and does not pass through the origin. Let $b$ be its closest distance to the origin and $\theta$ be the angle between its velocity and position vectors. This gives
$$\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 = \frac{1}{2}mr^2\omega^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{b}{\sin\theta}\right)^2\left(\frac{v\sin\theta}{r}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{b}{r}\right)^2 v^2 \neq \frac{1}{2}mv^2.$$
Therefore, it underestimates the kinetic energy as it does not account for the radial component of the velocity. So it is incorrect and $mv^2/2$ is the correct formula. As an extreme example, consider the case where $b=0$, i.e. the trajectory passes through the origin. $I\omega^2/2$ will then give zero even though the mass is moving. The reason the formula $I\omega^2/2$ does not apply here is because it requires that $\mathbf{v} = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{r}$. This condition is not satisfied here as the point mass is not moving in a pure rotation about the origin.
If the point mass were instead moving in a circular trajectory, then $\mathbf{v} = \boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf{r}$ holds and both formulae will be valid and equivalent.
